# Unable to use SDWebImage in my TableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6, sdwebimage

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use SDWebImage in my project but I'm always getting a different error and I'm a little bit desperated with that, I hope you can help me with that.

1. I tried following a tutorial to import the framework from gitHUB but I'm getting the error with the setImageWithURL that displays the error:
   No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'
2. When that error disappeared (like magic) I have a linker problem because I had to change to Linker Flags -ObjC and it's showing the error linker.
3. I tried to use CocoaPods but they are talking about some comand line and I'm lost with that.

What else can I try?

Edited:

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * carPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

[cell.carImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Hisoka.jpg"]];
```

No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to #1, you need to use a `UIImageView` NOT `UIImage`.

Comment: Use `cell.carImage` not `cell.carImage.image`.

Comment: Thanks Adam, your the only one helping me with this. I have updated the first message with the code, can you help me with that? I still have the same problem.

Comment: You need to change your `carImage` property to be a `UIImageView` not `UIImage`.